# D3: Drawing a histogram + heatmap

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

d3 noob here.

I'd like to draw something like this:

[image]
(http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883195)

But with a heat aspect, sort of like this:

[image]

Code (from above link):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.area {
  fill: steelblue;
}

</style>
<body>
<center>
<div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var svg = d3.select("div").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      // .attr("style", "stroke: #001")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");
});

</script>
</div>
</center>
</body>
```

Perhaps changing the area variable in someway? I could add another column to the data, say, color. But how would I apply the color to the "vertical line" of each day?

Thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the area where you set the class for the area, you'll want to return a different class based on the value. You could also use a scale.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Could you explain more?

Comment: You'll want to use the same logic as a choropleth. Take a look at how classes are defined here by using d3.Map(): http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606